# Submitting Instagram to iOS app

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I'm new to the site and new to developing so I'm looking for some general advice here.

I'm looking to build and app which works along side Instagram. So this is what I want to be able to do to start with.

- User opens app and can submit an already posted (and held on Instagram) photo to the app. The user at this point will need to be asked to log into their Instagram account. So for example they would select submit and it will open a window asking them to log into Instagram and then it will display all their available photos which they have posted.
- User selects the post they wish to submit to the app.
- Image displays on app in a gallery of submitted posts by all the other users for people to see.

Thats the basic premise. It's actually a lot more involved than that but I am learning and trying to keep it simple at the moment.

What I would like to know is. Is this possible, are there any guides which exist on how to do this.

What sort of process will I be looking at here. I've tried looking for posts on Instagram integration etc but I can't find anything similar to this.

Thanks in advance any help or pointers on where to even start will be helpful.

[error instagramdemo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ani2d.jpg)

Comment: You want to get instagram photos into your application?

Comment: yeah so its almost like a companion app. I don't want to transfer the photos to the app I kind of want to embed them. So they still stay on Instagram and can link back to that etc but I want users to be able to select a photo they have posted and send that into a main app gallery which displays all the users submissions.

Comment: absolutely possible.

Comment: well that's good to hear! I'm looking for directions to start heading in. I'm a baby developer so I am looking for resources etc. I am not looking for someone here to code my app for me but I'm struggling with starting points on how to achieve this.

Comment: To add further detail, I have signed up to Instagram developer, and have been practising various things in xcode yesterday so I understand basics etc.

Answer (score 0):

These libraries should help you get started,

https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit

https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk

1. You would have to create an application on the instagram developer
   portal, get a client ID for performing OAuth flow.
2. Ask your users to login to the instagram app and get the auth_token
   from instagram API.
3. Use the auth_token in all your requests basically.

The whole flow would have been implemented for you in the libraries I mentioned.

Say for example if you are using InstagramKit and after integrating/authorisation by the user getting images from the users feed would be as simple as below,

```
InstagramEngine *engine = [InstagramEngine sharedEngine];
[engine getSelfFeedWithSuccess:^(NSArray *media, InstagramPaginationInfo *paginationInfo) {
    // media is an array of InstagramMedia objects
    ...
} failure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {
    ...
}];
```

Steps to get InstagramKit up an running,

1. Download the InstagramKit from github.
2. Make sure you have cocoapods installed on your mac, refer
   https://cocoapods.org/ for help.
3. Open the InstagramKit-Example on terminal and run the following
   command,

   ```
   pod install
   ```
4. Wait for the pod to finish its magic.

Now you should have InstagramKit-Example.xcworkspace created in the InstagramKit-Example, open it and run.

I just did it now,

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I actually have already looked at these today but like i said I'm very new to this so I am struggling. I also tried to run the instagram kit in xcode but struggled with that :(

Comment: Where are you stuck?? Tell me let me help.

Comment: well i dragged all the files into xcode for the instagram kit, and i could see the layouts in the story board view all good but then i tried to run it to see what i was looking at but it failed to run. I assume I am doing something incorrect, I'm not even sure what I am looking at fully.

Comment: Did you try the example project they have provided? Did you install all cocoapods required by the example project?

Comment: at this point I'm very much still learning so I don't even know what cocoapods are. Basically i need a dummed down version of instructions of what to do ie download file open this replace this etc. Apologies as well I am an absolutely noob but I'm trying my best to learn.

Comment: No issues I will help you, I am downloading the pod files now

Comment: struggling with cocoapods. I clicked the install file from the kit but it's not done much. Do i need to separately install cocoapods. Struggling with that also :( Have tried reading the info on their site but not sure still what needs to be done.

Comment: @nohholmez if the answer helped you kindly up vote or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stpes to integrate instagram:

1)https://www.instagram.com/developer/ 
You would have to create an application on the instagram developer portal, get a client ID for performing OAuth flow.

2)Ask your users to login to the instagram app and get the auth_token from instagram API.

3) Use the auth_token in all your requests basically.

4) Download code from here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/mnuqck 
 and replace your clientid in my code. you will get response in code.

Comment: Download the code from 4th step and put required classes and frameworks from my code to your code. After that replace your client ID.

Comment: ok i have this and have it open in xcode where abouts do i need to put my client ID etc? Sorry for being so basic.

Comment: Go to AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: After that go to info.plist file where we have to add the same id in URL Types > URL Schemes and paste the client id. like ig8a77c0a6e7f9495eb23f9e0af67b92e7

Comment: ok I've done that and the build seems to succeed still. Thank you for your support! so now I'm looking for advice on where to go from here I guess.

Comment: I was just running the app and tested logging into to Instagram on the sim via it but it comes up with an authentication error is this correct?

Comment: can you give me your client id so that i can put it in my code and check the same?

Comment: 24a03a94594b4f04b4c618d48f7e5ac4

Comment: what you have added in your Redirect URI while creating your app on developer account?

Comment: i put a placeholder there from my website, do I need something different there? should it be instagram or something else?

Comment: yes change it to like :  ig1ab147664f1740f28a21a718c336bcf1://authorize

Comment: Tell me once you replace.

Comment: ive replaced it on my dev account

Comment: Go to Manage clients under instagram/developer. Then click edit under your app and uncheck Disable Implicit OAuth. It will now work as intended.

Comment: your REDIRECT URI should be : "ig" + "your clientId" + "://authorize"

Comment: you have add client id in info.plist file?

Comment: instagram is not allowing me to put that as my ID ive put in ig24a03a94594b4f04b4c618d48f7e5ac4//:authorize and it shows - Absolute URI must start with http://, https:// or a custom scheme:// any thoughts?

Comment: oh wait i can see a typo

Comment: success its now progressing although its not allowing me to auth sandbox mode, its saying invalid address

Comment: oh its because I am not a sandbox user. Well thank you very much for all your help it has been invaluable thank you!

Comment: Yes buddy. It's my pleasure.

Comment: I think there is some process of review. Instagram has changed recently. Go through it : https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/